# Example of a ring $A$ such that $\text{nil}(A)^n\neq 0 \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: commutative-algebra

I understand the somewhat default example with $k[X_1…]/(x_1,x_2^2…)$.

My question is, would $k[X_1…]/(x_1^2,x_2^2,x_3^2,…)$ work as well? Since for any $n$ I could just take the product of $x_1\cdot…\cdot x_n\neq 0$? Or is my understanding of ideal powers wrong?

Comment: That ring would work but the example you give doesn’t work because it always squares to $0$. For any given $n$, study the $n$th and $(n+1)$th powers of the element $x_1 + \ldots + x_n$.

Comment: @Arkady Hmm, I do not understand, why is "squares to 0" a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arkady is incorrect and you are correct. $\text{nil}(A)^n$ is spanned by all products of $n$ elements of $\text{nil}(A)$ so it does in fact contain $x_1 x_2 \dots x_n$ which is not zero, and this is already enough to show $\text{nil}(A)^n \neq 0$. (I think Arkady interpreted you to be considering $x_1 x_2 \dots x_n$ as an element of $\text{nil}(A)$ rather than as an element of $\text{nil}(A)^n$.)